# Union types of generic and non-generic in TypeScript arrays

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm playing around with TypeScript right now and was workshopping with the Playground page with an eye on converting an existing project to TypeScript.

I solved the problem that I was working on, but in the process I came across something that I don't quite understand. It regards the simplest of generic queue classes, shown partially here.

```
class Queue<T> {
  private store: T[] = [];
  public enqueue(item: T) {
    this.store.push(item);
  }
}

const queue = new Queue<number>();
queue.enqueue(5);       // works
queue.enqueue('six')    // properly errors
```

That works fine, of course. It also works fine if the backing store is typed as the union of two type variables.

```
class Queue<T, U> {
  private store: (T | U)[] = [];
  public enqueue(item: T | U) {
    this.store.push(item);
  }
}

const queue = new Queue<number, boolean>();
queue.enqueue(5);       // works
queue.enqueue(true);    // works
queue.enqueue('six')    // properly errors
```

However, when I make the store the union type of a type variable and an already-existing concrete type, type checking doesn't work on `enqueue`. (`Empty` is a singleton class, meant to emulate my old way of indicating an empty queue by returning a specific `EMPTY` object; I'm not sure what the best way to do that is but that's for another question.)

```
class Empty {
  // implementation of singleton class
}

const EMPTY = Empty.instance;

class Queue<T> {
  private store: (T | Empty)[] = [];
  public enqueue(item: T | Empty) {
    this.store.push(item);
  }
}

const queue = new Queue<number>();
queue.enqueue(5);       // works
queue.enqueue(EMPTY);   // works
queue.enqueue('six')    // also works, but it shouldn't
```

Introducing a type alias for `T | Empty` doesn't help, unsurprisingly.

Now in reality, this isn't a problem for me, as my queue implementation only stores type `T`. Only my `dequeue` has a union type in its signature, because it returns `EMPTY` if the store is empty (and that works fine). But I can certainly see a place for an array of a union type with a type parameter and a concrete type, and without digging deeply into it, it seems like something that should certainly be possible.

Is this something that I'm not understanding about the language, am I doing it wrong, or is it just a compiler limitation?

Comment: [Structural type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) means that any class is compatible with your `Empty`.  Add something non-static to `Empty` which `string` does not have, then you will get the error.

Comment: @artem Ugh, structural typing is going to take some getting used to. The idea of adding a member to a class for no reason other than to make it a different 'type' doesn't sit well, but I suppose that's the compromise for making it JavaScript compatible. Thanks for pointing that out.